# Copy data from another Workbook, unhide columns and turn off autofilters first, paste in current workbook and close workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get a macro that prompts a user to open an xlsm file, go to a specific tab, unhide the columns and turn off the filters, select all the data and paste into a new tab called *RRImport*.

Example: Working in a file called *MergedData.xlsm*, run macro to Open *Jul01Data.xlsm*, select *"Reviewed Data"* tab in *Jul01Data.xlsm*, unhide all columns and turn off all filters in the *"Reviewed Data"* tab, copy all data, Make a New sheet in *MergedData.xlsm* called *"RRImport"* and paste-special-values all the data in cell A1 of *"RRImport"*. Close *Jul01Data.xlsm* without saving any changes to it

```
Sub ImportSheet()


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "RRImport"
Sheets("RRImport").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Append to Merged Data", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlsm (*.xlsm),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
End If

wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").Select
' HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR, IR WON'T UNHIDE THE FILTERS    
    If wb2.AutoFilterMode Then
    wb2.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

Columns("A:M").Select
Selection.Copy
wb1.Sheets("RRImport").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work Now:

`AutoFilterMode` is a Worksheet Property not Workbook Property.

```
Sub ImportSheet()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Append to Merged Data", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlsm (*.xlsm),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FileToOpen)
End If

    If wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").AutoFilterMode Then
        wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

Dim ws As Worksheet

wb1.Activate
Set ws = wb1.Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet)
ws.Name = "RRImport"
wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").Columns("A:M").Copy

ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

wb2.Close False


End Sub
```

I have made few other changes also.

Answer (score 0):

So as this worked, I'll add the explanation.

First, you selected the worksheet, but then your code goes on while you're referring to the whole workbook, and not the worksheet.

That means, you don't need to select the worksheet, just refer to it same as you referred to the workbook.

What if instead

```
wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").Select
' HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR, IR WON'T UNHIDE THE FILTERS    
    If wb2.AutoFilterMode Then
    wb2.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
```

You wrote

```
    If wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").AutoFilterMode Then
    wb2.Sheets("Reviewed Data").AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
```

Comment: It will better if you explain what was wrong with the Code, and what did you change.  Just to make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much, it actually seems obvious now that you've written it out.

Comment: I added the explanation.